# How to disable formatting of numbers on CsvMapper

Tags: java, csv, parsing, export-to-csv

I'm writing data into the CSV file by using com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat. For the values like `37890194600590`(even it's defined as String in the model) I get `3.78902E+13`.

Here is how I initialized mapper:

```
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

How should I disable formatting?

And this is how I append body :

```
public  <T> void appendBody(List<T> list, Class<T> type, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    Assert.notNull(list, "list cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(type, "type cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(outputStream, "outputStream cannot be null");
    CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(type);
    mapper.writer(schema).writeValue(outputStream, list);
}
```

Comment: Do you have `3.78902E+13` in your csv file, or when you open it in Excel?

Comment: Ahh when I open it in excel